# StreamInsight 2.1 adapter to observer

Tags: linq, biztalk, streaminsight

I've been trying to implement the following adapter to connect StreamInsight with BizTalk:
http://seroter.wordpress.com/2010/07/09/sending-streaminsight-events-to-biztalk-through-new-web-soaprest-adapter/#comment-11635

At the end he does the following to bind the query to the adapter:

```
var allQuery = callTypeThreshold.ToQuery(
                     myApp,
                     "Threshold Events",
                     string.Empty,
                     typeof(WebOutputFactory),
                     webAdapterBizTalkConfig,
                     EventShape.Point,
                     StreamEventOrder.FullyOrdered);
```

Now, if I'm not mistaken this doesn't work anymore in StreamInsight 2.1 and I have no clue how to do this. Can anybody help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the legacy adapter model with the newer StreamInsight 2.1 API. To use an input adapter as a source, you'll need to use this overload of [Application.DefineStreamable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh995410%28v=sql.111%29.aspx).

So your code will look something like this:

```
var sourceStreamable = Application.DefineStreamable<TPayload>(
typeof(WebInputFactory),
webAdapterBizTalkConfig,
EventShape.Point,
AdvanceTimeSettings.IncreasingStartTime);
```

Now, if you want to use an output adapter as a sink, you'll need to use one of the overloads of [Application.DefineStreamableSink()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh995539%28v=sql.111%29.aspx).

So that code will look something like this:

```
var sink = Application.DefineStreamableSink<TPayload>(
typeof(WebOutputFactory),
webAdapterBizTalkConfig,
EventShape.Point,
StreamEventOrder.FullyOrdered);
```

Then just bind your streamable to the sink using the Bind() method followed by Run() to start the process and you are good to go.